# DG-Modules over CDG-algebras in the sense of rational homotopy theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-graded-algebras, rational-homotopy-theory

I don't know if this question is elementary or not. Suppose we have a rationalization $X_\mathbb{Q}$ of a simply connected topological space $X$. Then we can construct a CDG-algebra - a minimal Sullivan model $S$ corresponding to $X_\mathbb{Q}$.

How can we interpret a DG-module over $S$ in terms of $X_\mathbb{Q}$? Is it a "bundle over $X_\mathbb{Q}$" in some sense?

Comment: Roughly speaking, category of DG modules over S should correspond to the category of rational spectra over X_Q. These can be represented by chain complexes of vector bundles, for instance by taking a free resolution of the DG module.

Comment: @PhilTosteson , thanks for the comment, it looks very natural! Can you provide some literature where I can find precise statements?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't for the statements about spectra. However I remember in Sullivan's original paper he interprets free modules in terms of vector bundles with connection.

Comment: I think something of this kind is done in Vincent Braunack-Mayer, Hisham Sati, Urs Schreiber, "Gauge enhancement of super M-branes via parametrized stable homotopy theory", https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.01115 . There are lots of physics in there, but the things you're looking for are called, I guess, "parametrized spectra".